# docker Cannot find module '/var/www/server/build/app/Controllers/Http/UploadController'

Tags: docker, server, adonisjs-ace

i am using adonis js in my server side project ,i followed one of adonis js official docs to deploy  using pm2 module ,i successfully run outside my docker but  i am getting error only inside my project. i checked into my docker image everything correct in my project.

error

```
Error: Cannot find module '/var/www/server/build/app/Controllers/Http/UploadController'
Require stack:
```

i have file inside my image

[image]
dockerfile

```
# We'll use the Node slim image as a base cos it's light and nice
FROM node:lts
WORKDIR /var/www/server


# Copy package.json & package-lock.json to the root of the api dir
COPY package*.json ./

# Create an .env file by copying the .env.example file
# COPY .env .env
COPY . .

# Add node_modules to the envionmental path variable so we can run binaries easily
ENV PATH /var/www/server/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

USER root

# Install the good ol' NPM modules and get Adonis CLI in the game
RUN npm install --no-optional

# We'll use PM2 as a process manager for our Node server
RUN npm i -g pm2

# Copy everything to the root of the API service docker volume, and expose port to the outside world
COPY --chown=node:node . .

# Let all incoming connections use the port below
EXPOSE 3333

# CMD npm run pm2:start

# CMD npm run pm2:start
CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "start", "pm2.config.js" ] .
```

getting error when run docker image

```
C:\WinNMP\WWW\ac\server>docker run 2d6d4c30b76c
2021-08-12T16:43:44: PM2 log: Launching in no daemon mode
2021-08-12T16:43:45: PM2 log: [Watch] Start watching server
2021-08-12T16:43:45: PM2 log: App [server:0] starting in -cluster mode-
2021-08-12T16:43:45: PM2 log: App [server:0] online
Error: Cannot find module '/var/www/server/build/app/Controllers/Http/UploadController'
Require stack:
- /var/www/server/build/node_modules/@adonisjs/fold/build/src/Ioc/ImportAliases.js
- /var/www/server/build/node_modules/@adonisjs/fold/build/src/Ioc/index.js
- /var/www/server/build/node_modules/@adonisjs/fold/build/index.js
- /var/www/server/build/node_modules/@adonisjs/application/build/index.js
- /var/www/server/build/node_modules/@adonisjs/core/build/standalone.js
- /var/www/server/build/server.js
at /var/www/server/start/routes.ts(anonymous):34 <---------------------getting error
29
30
31  import Route from '@ioc:Adonis/Core/Route'
32  import LoginController from 'App/Controllers/Http/LoginController'
33  import DnsController from 'App/Controllers/Http/DnsController'
34  import UploadController from 'App/Controllers/Http/UploadController'<-------getting error
35  import ProductsController from 'App/Controllers/Http/ProductsController'
36  import SiteController from 'App/Controllers/Http/SitesController'
37  import { Request } from '@adonisjs/core/build/standalone';
38
39  Route.group(() => {
1 Module.require
  /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/require-in-the-middle/index.js:61
2 ImportAliases.resolve
  /var/www/server/build/node_modules/@adonisjs/fold/build/src/Ioc/ImportAliases.js:95
3 Ioc.require
  /var/www/server/build/node_modules/@adonisjs/fold/build/src/Ioc/index.js:294
4 Ioc.use
  /var/www/server/build/node_modules/@adonisjs/fold/build/src/Ioc/index.js:310
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue comes from my silly mistake however i made mistake on filename start with lowercase but it should be uppercase,This issue  not throw in windows operating system  when i move to production on linux it started throw.so why i am get confuse.